# How to make a case insensitive sorted list and rename the file names of a given folder?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I had about 500 `.JPG` and `.jpg` files in my folder `"c:\images\"`. How to ask
Mathematica to load all the `.jpg` and `.JPG` file names then make a case insensitive sorted list out of them, say `{"butterfly.jpg", "Fish.jpg", "marilyn.jpg", "Rabbit.JPG"... }`, and finally rename the files in the folder as:

[image]

```
fnameLst = FileNameTake/@ 
 FileNames[{"*.jpg", "*.JPG", "*.jpeg", "*.JPEG"}, "c:\\images", Infinity]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
(*Import file names and generate output names*)
folder = "C:\\images\\";
fnameLst = Sort[FileNameTake /@ FileNames[{"*.jpg", "*.JPG", "*.jpeg", "*.JPEG"}, folder, 
     Infinity]];
fnameNewLst = "img_" <> IntegerString[#, 10, 3] <> ".jpg" & /@ Range[Length@fnameLst];

(*Rename files*)
RenameFile[folder <> #[[1]], folder <> #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{fnameLst, fnameNewLst}]
```

Comment: The built-in `IntegerString` will do what your `NumberPad` is doing.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `IntegerString`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: paw, I see room for what I feel are improvements to this (good) answer.  May I edit your post or would you prefer that I post separately?

Comment: Feel free to edit my post senpai. Every edit that improves an answer is welcome, isn't this the philosophy of SE?